# How can I tell an ssh connection from an sftp one?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I am trying to restrict an ssh-user from executing unwanted commands through ssh from a remote host. For that I am using the forced command in the authorized_keys file that will allow the ssh-user to only execute a particular command.

If I did not set this, I am able to login via ssh and sftp.

How can I differentiate whether the remote connection is issued via ssh or sftp in a shell script?

The command that I am expecting is as follows and these both should work:-

ssh ssh-user@hostname test_scripts.sh

sftp ssh-user@hostname

I used the variable $TERM to differentiate between ssh and sftp. If it is sftp then the $TERM will return 'dumb'. But when we are passing a command through ssh then also the $TERM is returning dumb. 
Any idea how to differentiate?

Adding More details to the question :-

if [ $TERM = 'dumb' ]; then

$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND #If sftp, execute this

else

echo "This is ssh" #If ssh, execute this

fi

The above script is the invoked via forced command. When I am connecting remotely through ssh then I am getting the message as expected as "This is ssh"

ssh ssh-user@hostname
This is ssh

And when I am trying to connect through sftp then as expected the if condition got true and I am getting the sftp prompt.

sftp ssh-user@hostname
sftp>

But when I am passing a command along with the ssh command then the $TERM is set to dumb. So the if condition got true.

ssh ssh-user@hostname ls

I need to distinguish between the latter two methods in the above script. Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Restricted Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) - usually at /bin/rbash. I used this recently to achieve something similar to what you're trying to do (after farting about with chroot jails and not really getting anywhere).

For the users that I wanted to restrict, I set their terminal to /bin/rbash and their PATH to ${HOME}/bin. I then created a symlink to whatever commands I wanted them to be allowed to run in their ${HOME}/bin directory. I don't think it's 100% foolproof but it did the job with my users.

I haven't tested it for commands that are sent as part of the SSH command-line but I don't see why it wouldn't work so long as the user's shell is set to rbash.

Comment: This is a normal user in the server. He should be allowed the sftp prompt. But the user should not be allowed a prompt while connected via ssh. The user should be allowed to execute commands passed along with ssh as follows e.g :- ssh user@hostname <cmd>